# Apple Watch optimized email doesn't working

Tags: http-headers, html-email, apple-watch

I am currently trying to develop an Apple Watch optimized email. But none of the existing approaches like using headers:

```
Content-Type: text/watch-html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Type: text/X-watch-html; charset="utf-8"
```

doesn't work.
I also used the tricks described in the article on Litmus https://www.litmus.com/blog/how-to-send-hidden-version-email-apple-watch/
but it also had no effect. Apple Watch displays the standard text/html version of the email. Perhaps someone has a working solution or an explanation for the reason for this behavior.

Comment: Did you do this part: "Finally, the Watch will only fall back to your watch-html part if there’s something unsuitable in the standard HTML part. A simple remote image, such as a tracking bug or a hidden image, will do the trick."?

Comment: I don't quite understand what "simple remote image" means. I pasted a non-existing URL in the src attribute like `<img src = "site.com/image.jpg">` and also used a hidden image like `<img src = "path-to-image" style = "display: none;">` but it had no effect.

Comment: A remote image is an image hosted outside of the email, so, e.g. `https://via.placeholder.com/1x1`. You could test that e.g. `<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1x1">`, and then if that works, what I would do is save a 1x1 transparent gif, host that, and then use that. It may be that the `display:none` is making it not download.

Comment: i tried this way but it also didn't help